# JS(vue.js), How can i use linefeed? (\n)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, linefeed

Im making error messages with notification in Vue.js.

Tutorial Demo: https://admin.vuebulma.com/#/components/notification

Tutorial Codes: https://github.com/vue-bulma/vue-admin/blob/master/client/views/components/Notification.vue

```
openNotificationWithType: function (type) {
  openNotification({
    title: 'Error',
    message: 'Hello\nWorld',
    type: type
  })
}
```

in this code, when i use \n in string, it doesn't render it to linefeed.

So i have been searching how to apply linefeed in JS, but i can't exactly answer.

I tried below:

1)

```
 message: `Hello
 World`
```

2)

```
 message: 'Hello' + 
 '' + 'World'
```

3)

```
 message: 'Hello'
 + 'World'
```

4)

```
 message: 'Hello' + '\n' + 'World'
```

5)

```
 message: 'Hello<br/>World'
```

6)

```
 message: 'Hello<br>World'
```

7)

```
 message: `Hello \
 World`
```

8)

```
 message: [`Hello`,
           `World`].join(' ')
```

Results:

[results of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWQsU.png)

*** I'm in Mac OS.**

Comment: 1 and 4 are equivalent and do what you want, it just doesn't show up because of CSS styling. 2 and 3 produce no space at all, 7 and 8 produce just a blank not a linebreak.

Comment: @Bergi I tried 1 and 4, but they don't show what i want. Then how can i change and what do i change in CSS styling for showing what i want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The browser condenses all whitespace in text content into a single space, and you can't include HTML entities in normal (mustache) interpolation. You need [the `v-html` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML).

> ```
> <div v-html="rawHtml"></div>
> ```
>
> The contents of this `div` will be replaced with the value of the
> `rawHtml` property, interpreted as plain HTML - data bindings are
> ignored.

So you would have to modify the notification component to use `v-html`, and then use #5 with it.

Comment: It's not the code in html side, just JS part. But, Thanks for replying

Comment: The JS data for 1 and 4 are exactly what you want. It is the display that is keeping you from seeing it. You cannot display a newline in text content. You need an HTML `<br>` for that, and to insert HTML you have to use `v-html`.